# How to Convert the Current Time to milliseconds in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datetime, time

I am trying to convert the current time (system time) in to milliseconds ...is  there any inbuilt functions i can use to solve this easily .

For example i have used the following code to get the time and display it.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Time "+ String.Format("{0:mm:ss.fff}",DateTime.Now));
```

The output i get is

> Time 36:50.527

as in minutes:seconds.milliseconds

I need to convert the time i got now in to Milliseconds.

Comment: What to tag?visual studio?? or asp.net??? Or C# VB??

Comment: visual studio is an IDE… just saying…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a `TimeSpan` representing the time since your epoch. In our case, this is day 0. To get this, just subtract day 0 (`DateTime.Min`) from `DateTime.Now`.

```
var ms = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.MinValue).TotalMilliseconds;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Milliseconds since the alleged birth of christ: " + ms);
```

Comment: 10 years later it possible with `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()`

Answer (score 9):

You didn't specify, but usually when you need the time in milliseconds, it's because you're passing it off to a system that uses Jan 1st 1970 UTC as its epoch.  JavaScript, Java, PHP, Python and others use this particular epoch.

In C#, you can get it like this:

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc);
long ms = (long) (DateTime.UtcNow - epoch).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: Unix time is usually specified in seconds.

Comment: @Gusdor - that depends on the context.  For example in JavaScript, the `Date` constructor takes the time in milliseconds.